# Jquery deferreds: using filters with arrays of promises

Tags: jquery, jquery-deferred

I am a client-side newbie trying to wrap my head around jQuery Deferred objects, and in particular chaining. I have the case of one promise object substituting another promise object in its filtering working:

```
// works great. output: 
//  about to resolve top layer
//  top layer then results: {"id":"top_layer_deferred"}
//  about to resolve second layer item 0
//  top layer done: {"id":"second_layer_deferred"}
var top_layer_deferred = $.Deferred();

setTimeout(function() {
    console.log('about to resolve top layer');
    top_layer_deferred.resolve( { id: 'top_layer_deferred' } )
}, 10000 );

var top_layer_filter = top_layer_deferred.promise().then( function( results ) {

    console.log('top layer then results: ' + JSON.stringify(results) );
    var second_layer_deferred = $.Deferred();

    setTimeout(function() {
        console.log('about to resolve second layer item 0');
        second_layer_deferred.resolve( { id: 'second_layer_deferred' } )
    }, 2000 );

    return second_layer_deferred.promise();         
});


top_layer_filter.done( function(results) {
    console.log('top layer done: ' + JSON.stringify(results) );
});
```

Now I want to do the same thing, but return an array of promise objects in the filter code. (To keep things simple, I'm just putting one promise object on the array and not using any arguments to resolve.) But the filter code fires prematurely, as if it doesn't see its arguments:

```
// doesn't work. output:
//   about to resolve top layer
//   top layer then results: {"id":"top_layer_deferred"}
//   top layer done: 
//   about to resolve second layer item 0
var arr = [];
var top_layer_deferred = $.Deferred();

setTimeout(function() {
    console.log('about to resolve top layer');
    top_layer_deferred.resolve( { id: 'top_layer_deferred' } )
}, 10000 );

var top_layer_filter = top_layer_deferred.promise().then(function( results ) {

    console.log('top layer then results: ' + JSON.stringify(results) );
    var second_layer_deferred = $.Deferred();

    setTimeout(function() {
        console.log('about to resolve second layer item 0');
        second_layer_deferred.resolve()
    }, 2000 );

    arr.push( second_layer_deferred.promise() );
    return arr;             
});

top_layer_filter.done( function() {
    console.log('top layer done: ' );
});
```

I have tried replacing the line

```
top_layer_filter.done( function() {
```

with

```
$.when.apply(null,top_layer_filter).done( function() {
```

but that doesn't change the outcome.

Any ideas about what I'm missing?

Polly

Comment: What are you trying to do? In your current example, there's no point in adding deferred to an array as you're chaining your async action (one after the other), and array will only be used if you launch all async actions at the same time (so each action are independent) and want to wait for all to finish before doing something.

Comment: An array of promises is an array, not a promise!

Comment: @Simon: I'm trying to do this: (1) Kick off async action A. (2) When A completes, kick off independent actions B1, B2 .. Bn. (3) Then do something when B1, B2 ... Bn are all completed.I know there are ways to restructure the code to accomplish my goals without using the filter, but I'm interested in finding out why my filter approach isn't working.

Answer (score 1):

OK, my explanation that "an array of promises is an array, not a promise" clearly didn't get the point across. Here's a more complete explanation.

The jQuery 1.8+ documentation for `Deferred.then()` says of its `doneFilter`, `failFilter` and `progressFilter` arguments :

> These filter functions can return a new value to be passed along to
>   the promise's `.done()` or `.fail()` callbacks, or they can return
>   another observable object (Deferred, Promise, etc) which will pass its
>   resolved / rejected status and values to the promise's callbacks.

So, in jQuery 1.8+, the behaviour of `.then()` (more particularly of whatever is chained to it) is determined by what is returned. Returning an observable object (Deferred or Promise) is fundamentally different from returning any other type of object.

Your two code samples differ in this regard :

- in the first, `.then(function(){...})` returns a Promise, so the observable object passed down the chain is that Promise.
- in the second, `.then(function(){...})` returns an Array, so the observable object passed down the chain is a Promise, the status of which is identical to that which feeds `.then()` from its left (ie "resolved"), but with a resolved value of the Array.

If you can grasp the second point above, then you should be well on the way to seeing why you got the behaviour you observed.

To fix the issue, the second code sample needs to follow the same overall pattern as the first. The line `return second_layer_deferred.promise();` is critical. `arr` can be defined, populated and submitted to `$.when()` wholly inside `top_layer_deferred.then(function(){...})`.

```
var top_layer_deferred = $.Deferred();
setTimeout(function() {
    console.log('about to resolve top layer');
    top_layer_deferred.resolve('top_layer_deferred');
}, 5000);
var top_layer_filter = top_layer_deferred.promise().then(function(results) {
    console.log('top layer then results: ' + results);
    var second_layer_deferred = $.Deferred();
    var arr = [];
    for(var i=0; i<5; i++) {
        arr[i] = $.Deferred();
        setTimeout(function(ii) {//Note: double-wrap to form closure, ensuring correct i is reported.
            return function() {
                if(ii == 99) {//Edit here: try if(ii == 3)
                    console.log('about to reject second layer item ' + ii);
                    arr[ii].reject('second layer: ' + ii + ' rejected');
                }
                else {
                    console.log('about to resolve second layer item ' + ii);
                    arr[ii].resolve('second layer: ' + ii + ' resolved');
                }
            };
        }(i), 2000 + i * 2000);
        arr[i].done(function(r) {
            console.log('second layer : ' + r);
        }).fail(function(r) {
            console.log('second layer : ' + r);
        });
    }
    //At this point, arr is fully loaded with all the Deferreds it'll ever get,
    //so it's safe to apply $.when().
    $.when.apply(null, arr).done(function() {
        second_layer_deferred.resolve();
    }).fail(function(){
        second_layer_deferred.reject();
    });
    return second_layer_deferred.promise();
});
top_layer_filter.done(function() {
    console.log('top layer done');
}).fail(function() {
    console.log('top layer failed');
});
```

For good measure I have included a mechanism to cause the one of the second level Deferreds to fail (edit the code where indicated). You will see that

- when all second level Deferreds are successful, 'top layer done' is reported when all those Deferreds have been resolved.
- when any of the second level Deferreds fails, 'top layer failed' is reported immediately.